# jQuery length returns 1 when element assigned to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Why does this happen?** When I reference the element directly I get the expected result. When I assign the element to a variable the result is always 1.

When I write the code like this the result is always 1:

```
$dynamicNode = $(".dynamic");
$deleteNode  = $(".trash");

$deleteNode.click(function(){
    $count = $dynamicNode.length;
    console.log($count);
});
```

When I write the code like this the result is the actual number of elements with class .dynamic.

```
$deleteNode  = $(".trash");

$deleteNode.click(function(){
    $count = $(".dynamic").length;
    console.log($count);
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is due to the point at which the variables are defined. In the first example you get the elements when the page loads, so the `length` will always be the same in later click events.

In the second example you get the `length` at the point the button was clicked, hence it's always up to date with the state of the DOM.

Comment: oh lord,, this was such an obvious blunder,,, thanks.. I am now laughing at myself here.

Comment: try putting everything inside of $(document).ready(function() {       if it isn't already

Comment: @GRowing no problem, glad to help